# Send parameters from URL to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Countries(int id, int from=0)
```

I want my app to change FROM parameter in the URL and the controller, i want a button on my View that gives from+=10, how?

```
   <a class="k-button" href="@Url.Action("Countries", "Home",new {from+=10})">Next</a>
```

doesnt seem to work, so i want to call the Countries function every time i have /20 or /30 in my URL it must go +10 every time on button click or -10 doesn't matter, i just need to pass the value from my URL or View to the Controller function Countries, how? please help, thanks !

Comment: Do you have any variable that is having the current value of `from`?

Comment: You will need to pass a variable to the view to represent the new value you want in the url

Comment: @haim770 Variable? where what? It changes my View but when i Manualy change the FROM id to 10-20 etc.. then it opens a new view and gives me the info i want, so i JUST need to change the URL parameter i have /controler/id/from and how do i access the FROM and give it a value?

Comment: @AlminIslamovic, You need to persist the current value somewhere (e.g. database, session, etc). Then in the controller that generates the view, get the value, increment it and pass it to the view (e.g. as a `ViewBag` property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have the variable fixed in the Link i press like this:  `<a href="/#/Countries/{{s.id}}/0"> {{s.name}} </a>` it is not a variable but a number you are saying i need to make it like /id/from=10 as an example?

Comment: No I am saying you need `@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Countries", "Home", new  { id = ViewBag.ID, from = ViewBag.From })` and you need to pass the values of `id` and `from` to the view (in this case using `ViewBag` but it could be a view model)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass offset and count to the server.

Option 1:

Just define Page and PageSize in controller action and use it to filter the data from DB.

With this option your generated url will look like:

/Home/Countries?page=1&pagesize=10

Option 2:

You could define an object that has a lot more information along with Page# and PageSize

```
  public class DataSourceRequest
  {
    public int Page { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public IList<SortDescriptor> Sorts { get; set; }

    public IList<IFilterDescriptor> Filters { get; set; }

    public IList<GroupDescriptor> Groups { get; set; }

    public IList<AggregateDescriptor> Aggregates { get; set; }

    public DataSourceRequest()
    {
      this.Page = 1;
      this.Aggregates = (IList<AggregateDescriptor>) new List<AggregateDescriptor>();
    }
  }
```

**Update**:

OP says he want to pass a value incrementing on button click, suggesting you to 
define a JS global variable on the page, use this variable value in your link,  define a button click event in which you increment this variable by 10 every time.

**Update 2**:

You could achieve it this way, this works for me:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/1.11.2/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<h2>title</h2>
<a class="k-button">Next</a>

<script language="javascript">
    var itemCount = 0;

    $('.k-button').click(function () {

        var model = { id: itemCount, from : itemCount };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Countries", "Home")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: JSON.stringify(model)
        })
        .success(function (result) {
            alert(result);
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        });

        itemCount += 10;
    });

</script>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Test/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Countries(int id, int from = 0)
    {
        return Json(from);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have that,  `  public IEnumerable<Match> Matches { get; set; }
        public int From { get; set; }

        public int To { get; set; }
        public int MatchCount { get; set; }`  The problem is i want to change URL parameter /from and i can not from my View.. how do i make on button click from+=10 ? on view

Comment: @AlminIslamovic See my update and let me know if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yeah, i get it what you mean, but how do i access URL with JS? im kinda new to this.. :3

Comment: Since the link will redirect to a new page, a javascript variable would not work!

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, i didn't realize that. Updated my answer to provide one solution as per OP requirement but I agree what you proposed is better one.

Comment: @AlminIslamovic - Updated my answer. Please note you could consider your design to achieve same this in better way as Stephen suggested or as I suggested i.e. passing page information from UI.

Comment: you return a Json object in the answer? why is that? I already have a Json object`public ActionResult Countries(int id, int from=0)
        { string sqlQuery = @"select m.*  ..  s.id = ?"; 

uery.SetQueryRange(from, 10);
            Match[] resultallCountries = query.Execute();

            result.Matches = resultallCountries.
            return PartialView(result);
`

Comment: Just for example, your action can remain same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how i have done it: `

```
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.MatchCount / 20; i++)
{
    if (i == Model.To)
        {
        <span>@(i + 1)</span>
        }
    else
    {
        <a id="Link" href="/#/Countries/@Model.Id/@(i *20)" data-pageindex="@i"
           class="pager">@(i + 1)</a> 
    }
```

}`

where i * 20 is the number i display and Model.Id is the current page ID. it is working so yeah..